# Android what will happen if the uploading app APK package name already taken?

Tags: android

What will happen if the uploading app APK package name already taken?

Will Google check the package name when upload like how a site check for taken username (as example)?
Or will Google just let it slide...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't upload APK with package that is already taken. You should upload version as soon as you start developement and not publish that to make sure it will be your if you really like your package name.

Answer (score 0):

The package name has to be unique.  You will receive an error if you try to upload a package name that is already taken.

The package name is also used for the URL on the Play Store, so if you use the same package name it would not work.

Answer (score 0):

Two apps with the same package name cannot be put onto the market, this is due to security. Even if the developer unpublishes their app and you try and upload your own with the same package it will get rejected.